# bitcoinpaperwallet.com scam lost 14.5 BTC

Tags: transactions, wallet, fraud, theft, hack

Last night I made the mistake of using the website (while offline) to generate a wallet. I sent 0.1 then 14.5 BTC to it, and then 1 min later 14.51 was sent out to another paper wallet

here is the wallet I created and you can see the transactions
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1BxPiuddFh7vz83BCFM9ZKUV75jUJyvJUv

any advice on what I can do. I've accepted the loss and the lesson (should have used the offline generator) but want to make sure this doesn't happen to others

Comment: Which is the website?

Comment: @LucaBlight in the title

Comment: *"I just lost half a million dollars.... but I've accepted the loss and the lesson"*.   I don't think even Buddah would be calm under these conditions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What did I do wrong that caused me to lose bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/85038/what-did-i-do-wrong-that-caused-me-to-lose-bitcoin) - the asker of that question used bitcoinpaperwallet.com and a comment says *"The site bitcoinpaperwallet.com was sold in April 2018 github.com/cantonbecker/bitcoinpaperwallet And after this time many people wrote that their bitcoins were stolen."*

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry for your loss, unfortunately, there is no way to get those Bitcoins again.

I have seen other people who got scammed by this website like this one: https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/cyd6uj/bitcoinpaperwalletcom_scam_or_not_4_btc_stolen/

The best way to make the private key offline is using trustworthy software and when the computer will never connect to the internet again, otherwise, it will be possible to send the private key created to someone else when the computer is online again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been scammed out of that much money, you might be able to afford to hire a Bitcoin tracking expert where they get a cut of any returned funds, perhaps, just a suggestion.

Forensic experts for Bitcoin do exist. There were people investigating the Mt Gox collapse for instance. They will help you gain evidence, and then you can go to law enforcement to catch the suspect.

Also, the domain name may be a way to find out more about the person, if you can prove criminal activity, then you may be able to get info from the domain registration company.

If you correctly find out the domain is a scam, then it can be reported in a Google Phishing Report, so that this does not happen to others.

Answer (score 0):

The funds are still in the scammers wallet as of this moment, as such I'd hold off on paying any experts just yet. It's when it starts to move that something can be traced. I'd report it to law enforcement and get a crime reference. This way when the funds start moving, if it is identified that they have gone to an exchange you might be able to do something (very small chance but still). Basically you or someone you employ can try to contact the exchange, explain the theft and provided the law enforcement reference. The exchange may then freeze funds awaiting a further input from law enforcement, at this point you can then try to get the local police to actively investigate the matter through engaging with the exchange. It would also be worth submitting a report on bitcoinabuse.com as this is used as an open source data repository for risk assessment tools by some entities.